# Soft keyboard not come in WebView

Tags: android

My android app has a webview. Where i load a webpage to give user name and password. But now a problem is no soft keybord is not comming.Please help anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May help you this code:

```
 webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
 webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
   {
    @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
      switch (event.getAction())
      {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!v.hasFocus())
            {
                v.requestFocus();
            }
            break;
       }
      return false;
    }
   });
```